# Benchmarking hard disks on Mac OS X SL

Tags: mac-osx, hard-drive, benchmark, hdparm

On Linux I would usually use "hdparm -tT device" when I want a quick idea of how an hard drive is performing compared to another; having switched to Mac OS X a few months back I have yet to find something similar and as easy to use.

I have read that diskutil can do similar things on Mac but I am not clear about how I should use it to do something similar to the hdparm command above.

Any ideas on how to do this or on alternatives?
Thanks!

Comment: You probably don't need to benchmark it, all Apple users will tell you that its performing GREAT either way ;)

Answer (score 2):

Using file copy in general and `dd` in particular isn't the great way to measure I/O performance. This is a very good wrap up about WHY it's so.

https://barreto.home.blog/2014/08/18/using-file-copy-to-measure-storage-performance-why-its-not-a-good-idea-and-what-you-should-do-instead/

Microsoft DiskSPD (There's a Linux port for sure!) and a cross-platform FIO (Which is probably recommended...) should be used instead.

https://github.com/microsoft/diskspd/actions

https://github.com/microsoft/diskspd-for-linux

https://github.com/axboe/fio

Here's some HOWTO guides on using both DiskSDP and FIO. Windows, Linux, and MacOS X accordingly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/disks-benchmarks

https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Block/References/samplefiocommandslinux.htm

https://www.nivas.hr/blog/2017/09/19/measuring-disk-io-performance-macos/

Answer (score 1):

Some tools I use:

- [Xbench](http://www.xbench.com/)
- [Diskfire](http://factorial.co.nz/tools/index.html)
- [bonnie64](http://code.google.com/p/bonnie-64/)

I'm sure there are others I"m not thinking of at the moment.  My current favorite is probably DIskfire.  I would also check out the [Xsanity](http://www.xsanity.com) forums, because they're experts at OS X disk performance, especially in Xsan.

Comment: The latter 2 are dead links and the 1st one seems last updated in 2006 and doesnt work on external USB drives in Mac OS 10.9.

Answer (score 1):

I have yet to find an equivalent for `hdparm` on macOS.

Someone mentioned using `dd` to get at least a basic idea with a command that is available, which is a little bit helpful. They admitted to not knowing the macOS command line, so here is a Mac specific version:

`dd if=/dev/disk0s1 of=/dev/zero bs=4096 count=10240`

This will report a very basic bytes per second.

Answer (score 0):

(bear in mind I never used Mac CLI so there can be little differences from what I write)

you could try dd:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/zero bs=4096 count=10240 iflag=direct
```

This will copy 40MiB of data from the beginning of the drive and show you the average speed.

Comment: I wouldn't trust this -- in my experience, OS X's version of `dd` seems to move data much slower than the devices are capable of.

Comment: The Mac version of `dd` doesn't have the `iflag` command line argument.